# Different @@Trancount results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have an application running in two servers. When I try using SQL Profiler for tracing whats going on in my database when saving data. 
I received `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN` in Server **A** after trying to insert data in database. While on the other server I received `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN`  in Server **B**.

Any ideas what cause the rollback tran? I am using the same application in both servers.

Comment: `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN` is part of your code. Find it and change it.

Comment: @sqluser Im sorry but I believe I don't have a code like that. This is the code that closer to that. Select Case Button.Key
Case "save"
    Conn.BeginTrans
    If jsSave Then
        Conn.CommitTrans
        Me.jsGrid.CommitStatus
        CurrentStatus = adSaved
    Else
        Conn.RollbackTrans
        Me.jsGrid.RollbackStatus

Comment: Check your SQL codes. Any procedures?

Comment: Yeah I do have some stored procedures but unfortunately none of them have if @@trancount > 0 rollback tran. That is why its very confusing

Comment: Look for some BEGIN TRAN in your code.

Comment: @Beto : what should i do with Begin Tran code?

Comment: Every BEGIN TRAN open a transaction (explicit) for special needs and increase @@TRANCOUNT, then you can make a ROLLBACK TRAN or COMMIT TRAN depends conditions. So, you look for every BEGIN TRAN you MUST have your equivalent close (commit or rollback).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN` somewhere in your database objects.

To find a text in your databse objects, you can try following query:

```
DECLARE @Search VARCHAR(255)
SET @Search='IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRAN'

SELECT DISTINCT so.name AS [Object_Name]
                ,so.type_desc AS [Type]
FROM sys.sql_modules AS ssm 
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS so ON ssm.object_id = so.object_id
WHERE ssm.definition LIKE '%' + @Search + '%'
ORDER BY [Type], [Object_Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

Every BEGIN TRAN open a transaction (explicit) for special needs and increase @@TRANCOUNT, then you can make a ROLLBACK TRAN or COMMIT TRAN depends conditions.

So, you look for every BEGIN TRAN you MUST have your equivalent close (commit or rollback).